# In-App product mismatch in the live version of iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, mobile-application

I am having the problem that I have one of my app is live on the apple app store which has In-App purchase products, In the already available application end user getting only 1 product which is available for sale on the developer console.

Now, I have submitted the new app version with minor bug fixes and few other changes to apple for app review process and I got the rejected.
Reason: for the Apple team review My in products showing including the state `Developer Removed from sale` and `Clear for sale`

Why it is showing like this, is there any policy update from Apple for in-app products or what?

Below is the reply from Apple team

```
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
```

We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

Specifically, the “Standard Monthly Subscription” and the “SOLARO 10 Class Pack”.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please be sure to take action and submit your in-app purchases and upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about how to offer in-app purchases in iTunes Connect Developer Help.

Once you've submitted your in-app purchases and uploaded a new binary, we can proceed with your review.

and attached this image as of my app[image]

Comment: Can you clearly state the Apple Team Review Rejection reason here? It isn't clear.

Comment: @SachinVas I have updated question, please check